# What is the origin of the "imaginary" in imaginary numbers?

Tags: mathematics

When was the imaginary number, i, introduced? Why was it called imaginary? Isn't it just as imaginary as a negative number? Aren't all numbers imaginary, for that matter?

I am not interested in the notation of the number (i or j). I'm interested in why it is called imaginary.

The two questions of which this is supposed to be a copy don't ask why it is called imaginary.

Comment: Useful books on this topic: [**An Imaginary Tale: The Story of** $\sqrt{-1}$](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691169241) by Paul J. Nahin and [**Imagining Numbers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0312421877) by Barry Mazur.

Comment: @MarioALLEGRANZA. No. I am not interested in the notation of the number. Im interested in why it is called imaginary.

Comment: Some argue that Descartes was first to use the name in his *La Geometrie* (1637) - see [Mathword - I](https://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html).  Others, such as Leo Corry, argue that Descartes used the name *false* but described them as *imaginary* in the sense that they can only be imagined.